# Get attribute of parent of parent of a multilevel inherited class

Tags: python

Let's imagine the following classes structure:

```
class A:
    def t(self):
        print("a")

class B(A):
    def t(self):
        super().t()
        print("b")
```

I want, from a class `C`, that inherits from `B`, to run only `A.t()` method using `super` keyword, so that running

```
c=C()
c.t()
```

will print only

```
a
```

For information, let's suppose that I do want `C` to act like `B`, *excepted* for the method `t()`, which will have to completely bypass `B.t()` to override `A.t()`.

I tried

```
class C(B):
    def t(self):
        super().super().t()
```

which returns `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'super'`.

I also tried

```
class C(B):
    def t(self):
        A.t()
```

which returns `TypeError: t() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong. Can someone show me how to overide to the method of the second parent, while still inheriting from the first parent?

Comment: If you want C to not act like B, then maybe inheritance is the wrong mechanism for this.  If you explain what these classes are and why you don't want B, it might be easier to help.

Comment: I want C to act like B, except for C.t(), which completely overrides B.t()

Comment: You can use `A.t(self)`, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: There's the method, which is actually f*ck idea of inheritance. You can call `A.t(self)`.

Comment: Ok I understand. Rest assured that it's not going to be used in anything important, or critical. See this as a quick hot swap. I am still glad that you gave the warning that it is not the recommended way, I hope it will be seen by other users.

Comment: `class C(B): t = A.t` is also a thing you can do

Comment: This is a bad idea, because `C` is reaching past the interface that `B` presents to subclasses. `A.t` is not part of `B`'s subclass interface. Subclasses are not supposed to have access to it. If subclasses *are* supposed to have access to it, `B` should do something to expose access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can use `A.t(self)` to achieve your goal.

But .. it seems like it's not really necessary to do this.

```
class A:
    def real_t(self):
        print("a")

    def t(self):
        self.real_t()


class B(A):
    def t(self):
        self.real_t()
        print("b")


class C(B):
    def t(self):
        self.real_t()
        print("c")
```

Comment: This is fragile if there are other classes in the hierarchy.

Comment: @o11c, this answer is based on comments under question, where author described what he wanted to achieve. As I understood, this should fit as a simple solution for this particular "issue". Of course this can't be used as universal recommendation or recommendation at all. It's just an option, which I find better than call method from "superbase" class by it's name.

Comment: I marked it as answer because it *is* the answer to my question. However, I feel like I should promote the more usual ways of solving problems of class hierarchy. I too, believe that `A.t(self)` is a terrible way of fixing bad code design, but it really works in the way that it indeed reaches the parent of the parent of the class. I highly recomend other users to fix their class hierarchy if they can before attempting this.

Answer (score 2):

You can redesign your class hierarchy such that `B` and `C` both inherit from a common subclass of `A`, which implements every method that your current `B` class implements except the method `t`, which is left to the new `B` class to implement on its own:

```
class A:
    def t(self):
        print("a")

class SubA(A):
    def other_method(self):
        pass

class B(SubA):
    def t(self):
        super().t()
        print("b")

class C(SubA):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This is atrocious and you should never do it, but it *is* possible.

Remember that `super()` is short for `super(__class__, self_or_whatever_the_first_argument_is)`, but it's legal to pass *any* class in the MRO as the first argument.

The below code will work even if globals are replaced (e.g. by `imp.reload`), but not if something else inherits from `B` and gets between C and B in the MRO. If you hard-code B in place of `next_class`, you will instead skip such classes and it will break if globals are replaced.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class A:
    def t(self):
        print("a")

class B(A):
    def t(self):
        super().t()
        print("b")


class C(B):
    def t(self):
        s = super()
        # s.__self_class__ == self.__class__ == type(self) == F
        mro = s.__self_class__.mro()
        # unless globals are replaced, s.__thisclass__ == __class__ == C
        thisclass_index = mro.index(__class__)
        next_class = mro[thisclass_index+1]
        # unless globals are replaced or something else inherits from B, next_class == B
        super(next_class, self).t()
        print('c')

class D(A):
    def t(self):
        super().t()
        print('d')

class E(A):
    def t(self):
        super().t()
        print('e')

class F(D, C, E):
    def t(self):
        super().t()
        print('f')

def main():
    assert F.mro() == [F, D, C, B, E, A, object]
    print('This should print the letters `aecdf` in order:')
    F().t()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: For anyone who thinks they ought to "fix" `__class__` to `self.__class__`, no. `__class__` is correct. [It's a real thing.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) `self.__class__` is a different thing, and it's the *wrong* thing if further subclasses are created.